# Reading Cyrillic characters from file in perl

Tags: perl, file, encoding

I'm having trouble reading Cyrillic characters from a file in perl.

The text file is written in Notepad and contains "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъьюя".
Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open FILE, "text.txt" or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {
    print $_;   
}
```

If I save the text file using the ANSI encoding, I get:

```
рстуфхцчшщъыьэюяЁёЄєЇїЎў°∙·№■
```

If I save it using the UTF-8 encoding, and I use the function decode('UTF-8', $_) from the package Encode, I get:

```
Wide character in print at test.pl line 11, <TEXT> line 1.
```

and a bunch of unreadable characters.

I'm using the command prompt in windows 7x64

Comment: What's encoding was used for the file? What encoding does your terminal use?

Comment: I'm using the command prompt in windows 7

Comment: Type `chcp` and prepend `cp` to the number obtained to get the answer to my second question. (e.g. `cp437` for me.) What about my first question?

Comment: First question: I try 2 encodings 8-bit ansi and utf-8. Second question cp866

Comment: "ANSI" is not an encoding. cp1251, probably.

Comment: [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252) doesn't have cyrilic chars. ("Windows-1252" and "cp1252" are the same thing. Perl accepts either name. Same goes for 1251.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're decoding your inputs, but "forgot" to encode your outputs.

Your file is probably encoded using [cp1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1251).

Your terminal expects [cp866](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866).

Use

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp866)';
use open IO => ':encoding(cp1251)';
open(my $FILE, '<', 'text.txt')
   or die $!;
```

or

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp866)';
open(my $FILE, '<:encoding(cp1251)', 'text.txt')
   or die $!;
```

Use `:encoding(UTF-8)` instead of `:encoding(cp1251)` if you saved as UTF-8.